# Triggered send job stopped error - OMM_SLOT_RELEASED_TO_ERR

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, email-studio

All of a sudden, we are getting following error for one of our triggered emails -

**Error Code:** OMM_SLOT_RELEASED_TO_ERR

**Error message:** Job slot was failed due to being detected with a stale heartbeat over the maximum number of times allowed in the past hour. Stale heartbeats normally trigger an automatic release and retry of the job slot. However this job slot has repeatedly failed when retried. This may indicate that mail servers are being put into a bad state when they attempt to run this job or this job in combination with other jobs. It is being put into an error state so that the issues putting mail servers into a bad state can be investigated.
Once you resolve the error, you can restart the Triggered Send in Email Studio from the Interactions tab.

Does anyone encountered it before? What does stale heartbeat mean and why did the error occur?  If you had such an error how did you resolve it ?

Comment: I would simply restart your triggeredsend

Comment: Thanks for the info. We are using a transactional API  event for this journey and In Interaction tab I can only find triggered sends(all journeys). Where should transactional journeys be restarted, as I cant find them under triggered sends?

Comment: I would either make a patch call to update it to active or possibly edit the email activity on the canvas and click done